# Return the same Div when clicking + button in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-functional-component

i build this div element here , which at the end has a "+" button and a "x" button . The plus button adds the same div just below it and the x or clear button removes it . Now how can i render the same div when clicking plus button or when clicking x , i tried multiple ways but i couldn't do it , this is my code. One way that i think of is doing recursion but it doesn't work.

[image]

```js
function IpRangeInput() {
  const [ipRange, setIpRange] = useState<string>('');
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState<string>('');
  const [fromValue, setFromValue] = useState<string>('');
  const [toValue, setToValue] = useState<string>('');

  const handleInputValue = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setInputValue(event?.target.value);
  };

  const handleAdd = () => <IpRangeInput />;

  return (
    <Box className={styles.inputContainer}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <FormControl className={styles.inputContainer__select}>
          <Select
            defaultValue="Select"
            id="select-label"
            value={ipRange}
            onChange={(e) => setIpRange(e.target.value)}
          >
            <MenuItem value="IP/CIDR">IP / CIDR</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="Range">Range</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>

        {ipRange === 'Range' ? (
          <>
            <span className={styles.inputContainer__text}>From</span>
            <Box
              className={[
                styles.inputContainer__input,
                styles.inputContainer__newInput,
              ].join(' ')}
            >
              <TextField
                value={fromValue}
                onChange={(e) => setFromValue(e.target.value)}
              />
            </Box>

            <span className={styles.inputContainer__text}>To</span>
            <Box
              className={[
                styles.inputContainer__input,
                styles.inputContainer__newInput,
              ].join(' ')}
            >
              <TextField
                value={toValue}
                onChange={(e) => setToValue(e.target.value)}
              />
            </Box>
          </>
        ) : (
          <Box className={styles.inputContainer__input}>
            <TextField value={inputValue} onChange={handleInputValue} />
          </Box>
        )}

        <IconButton
          className={styles.inputContainer__addButton}
          onClick={handleAdd}
        >
          <AddIcon />
        </IconButton>

        <IconButton
          className={styles.inputContainer__clearButton}
          onClick={handleAdd}
        >
          <Clear />
        </IconButton>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно хранить список блоков в родительском компоненте в стейте, например, как массив айди. Каждому блоку присваивается свой айди. И в итоге нажатие кнопок будет триггерить удаление или добавление айди в массив или из него

Ваш итоговый код:

```html
function Parent () {
  const [list, setList] = useState([0])
  
  const handleAdd = (id) => setList(prevList => prevList.push(id + 1))

  const handleClear = (id) => setList(prevList => {
    prevList.splice(id, 1)
    return prevList
  })

  return (
    list.map((item) => {
      <IpRangeInput
        key={item}
        id={item}
        handleAdd={handleAdd}
        handleClear={handleClear}
      />
    })
  )
}

function IpRangeInput({ handleAdd, handleClear, id }) {
  const [ipRange, setIpRange] = useState<string>('');
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState<string>('');
  const [fromValue, setFromValue] = useState<string>('');
  const [toValue, setToValue] = useState<string>('');

  const handleInputValue = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setInputValue(event?.target.value);
  };

  const handleAdd = () => handleAdd(id)
  const handleClear = () => handleAdd(id)

  return (
    <Box className={styles.inputContainer}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <FormControl className={styles.inputContainer__select}>
          <Select
            defaultValue="Select"
            id="select-label"
            value={ipRange}
            onChange={(e) => setIpRange(e.target.value)}
          >
            <MenuItem value="IP/CIDR">IP / CIDR</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="Range">Range</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>

        {ipRange === 'Range' ? (
          <>
            <span className={styles.inputContainer__text}>From</span>
            <Box
              className={[
                styles.inputContainer__input,
                styles.inputContainer__newInput,
              ].join(' ')}
            >
              <TextField
                value={fromValue}
                onChange={(e) => setFromValue(e.target.value)}
              />
            </Box>

            <span className={styles.inputContainer__text}>To</span>
            <Box
              className={[
                styles.inputContainer__input,
                styles.inputContainer__newInput,
              ].join(' ')}
            >
              <TextField
                value={toValue}
                onChange={(e) => setToValue(e.target.value)}
              />
            </Box>
          </>
        ) : (
          <Box className={styles.inputContainer__input}>
            <TextField value={inputValue} onChange={handleInputValue} />
          </Box>
        )}

        <IconButton
          className={styles.inputContainer__addButton}
          onClick={handleAdd}
        >
          <AddIcon />
        </IconButton>

        <IconButton
          className={styles.inputContainer__clearButton}
          onClick={handleClear}
        >
          <Clear />
        </IconButton>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks i translated your solution , modified it a little bit , but it still worked thanks !